# Trying to call a Class in an Instance Variable

Tags: java

1. Add an instance variable called currentPhrase to hold the current round’s Phrase

My error message is "Phrase cannot be resolved to a variable"
I feel like it has something to do with new String()? maybe.
Or could it be something like Phrase phrase = new Phrase();

```
package edu.htc.java1.phrasegame;
import edu.htc.java1.phrasegame.model.*;

public class PhraseGameController {

    public void currentPhrase() {
        String p = new String();
        p = Phrase;
    }

}
```

and

```
package edu.htc.java1.phrasegame.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Phrase { 
    public void setPhrase(String phrase) {
        this.phrase = phrase; 
    }

    private String phrase;

    public Phrase(String phrase) {      
        phrase = phrase.toUpperCase();
        for(char c : phrase.toCharArray()) {
            letters.add(new Letter(c));
        }   
    }

    public String getPhrase() {
        return phrase;  
    }

    ArrayList<Letter> letters = new ArrayList<Letter>();

    public ArrayList<Letter> getLetters() {
        return letters;
    }


    public boolean guessLetter(char c) {
        // convert received character to letter
        Letter letter = new Letter(c);

        // loop through your list of letters
        for(Letter l : letters)   {
            // if list of letters contains same letter as the one you received then return true
            if(l.getLetter() == letter.getLetter()) {
                letter.unhide();
                // return true;
            }
        }

        // we did not find the letter, so we return false
        return false;   
    }
}
```

Comment: "1.Add an instance variable called currentPhrase to hold the current round’s Phrase" This is not what you are doing. You have made a Method called currentPhrase with a void return type, and then in that method you make a new string called p and assign it the undeclared variable Phrase's value, hence the error message.

Comment: public void currentPhrase(Phrase); 
 Phrase three = new Phrase();     //Somewhat like this?

Comment: This is the 2nd question of yours where you do something like `String p = new String(); p = Phrase;` What do you think that is supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An instance variable is a property of the class.

```
public class MyClass {
    private static String classVariable;

    private String instanceVariable;

    public String instanceMethod () {
        String localVariable = "hey";
    }

    public static String classMethod {

    }
}
```

To instantiate a variable you have to use the `new` keyword:

```
SomeClass someInstance = new SomeClass();
```

Or if you use generics:

```
List<SomeType> myList = new ArrayList<SomeType>();
```

So in your case it should be:

```
public class PhraseGameController {
    private Phrase p = new Phrase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that first you will have to import this package:

```
edu.htc.java1.phrasegame.model;
```

into your PhraseGameController class. by adding this below the package declaration, but above the class declaration:

```
import edu.htc.java1.phrasegame.model.*;
```

Then you will make a new variable in that class called currentPhrase like so:

```
private Phrase currentPhrase;
```

What you do with it from there is sort of beyond the scope of your question.